# Celery Task Custom tracking method

Tags: python, flask, celery, celery-task

My main problem relies on the fact that i need to know if a task is still queued, started or revoked.

I cant do this with celery and redis because 24hs after the results are in redis they are deleted.

I had some ideas but i think the most solid one is to have a database tracking and manually adding the critical information that i need of the task a user is running.

There are methods for that that can run before a task start and i can also manually work with the database when i create task or revoke them right? i wont create a new row for every task but instead just updating a row for every user because im only interested in the last task of every user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to combine multiple approaches. If your results expire in the backend (which is reasonable), you have to employ different storage like a database for long-term archiving of tasks' states. For a start, you can enable [`task_track_started`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-track-started) so that tasks report `STARTED` status when worker starts the execution). Then periodically check the results backend for status updates of tasks that are not in ready states (`SUCCESS`, `FAILURE` and `REVOKED`). If they are in the final state, remove the result from the backend using `forget()` method.

The only problem is with revoked tasks. If there are no workers available, revoking the task has no effect (that's why you should always wait for reply when calling a revoke). If the workers are busy and thus the task remains in the message queue, workers just note that such task should be discarded when they pick it up from the queue, but it's stored only in the worker's state. Once they take it, they drop the task and result contains `REVOKED` status eventually. The key is to note that revoked tasks are only maintained in the workers' state and so you should use [`--statedb`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-statedb) parameter to persist the state in case the worker crashes. Otherwise, already revoked tasks will happily get processed by the same or another worker.

Your best option I guess is to call the revoke command and if you get a reply from workers, set internal status of the task in your database to something like `FLAGGED_REVOKED`. In the status update loop, update the revoked task's status only if it's not `PENDING`.

I have a simple job scheduling app that employs APScheduler as a scheduler and Celery as a execution layer. Information about the jobs, job runs and the schedule are kept in MongoDB. Here is a the code I use to cancel the job:

```
database = scheduler._jobstores['default'].collection.database
collection = database['runs']

run = collection.find_one({'job_id': job_id, '_id': run_id})
if run.get('task_state') in ('PENDING', 'RECEIVED', 'STARTED', 'RETRY'):
    reply = celery.control.revoke(run['task_id'], terminate=terminate, reply=True)
    if reply:
        collection.update_one({'_id': run['_id']},
                              {'$set': {'task_state': 'FLAGGED_REVOKED'}})
    else:
        raise Exception('Failed to revoke the task (no reply received)')
else:
    raise Exception('Job execution cannot be canceled')
```

This is my status update code (that's kept as an internal APScheduler job to run every few seconds):

```
database = scheduler._jobstores['default'].collection.database
collection = database['runs']

runs = collection.find({
    'task_id': {'$exists': True},
    'task_state': {'$nin': ['SUCCESS', 'FAILURE', 'REVOKED']}
})
for run in runs:
    result = AsyncResult(run['task_id'],
                         backend=celery.backend, app=celery)
    if run['task_state'] == 'FLAGGED_REVOKED' and result.state == 'PENDING':
        update = {'task_state': 'FLAGGED_REVOKED'}
    else:
        update = {'task_state': result.state}
    if result.state == 'FAILURE':
        update['exception'] = str(result.result)
        update['traceback'] = result.traceback
    elif result.state == 'SUCCESS':
        update['result'] = result.result
    if result.date_done:
        date_done = dateparser.parse(result.date_done) \
            if isinstance(result.date_done, str) else result.date_done
        update['finish_time'] = date_done
    try:
        collection.update_one({'_id': run['_id']}, {'$set': update})
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to update task status: %s', str(e))
    else:
        if result.state in ['SUCCESS', 'FAILURE', 'REVOKED']:
            result.forget()
```

Comment: Its a really solid solution, i just dont understand why celery leaves all this task to the developer and doesnt provide some functions for this but i can think reasons for that. I will take many of the concepts you gave me here, the most important being the fact that revoked task only revoke or appear revoked if there are workers aviabe,  so thank in advance, i will try to implement these functionalities.

Comment: the thing is i think signals solve partially my problem, i remove the task from the database on postrun and that way my problem partially ends. So i can know if the task had run because it doesnt exist any more as a queued task and the only problem relies on the revoked status.  could i potentially use the signal that runs on revoked to delete the task when is flagged as revoked or the revoked signal runs when the worker tries to run a flagged task ? if so i could take it from the db when i manually revoke it... i dont know really im new to celery

Comment: I think the problem partly arises from the fact that you are employing a distributed system, so the problem is inherent. You might use signals, but I try to keep components of my app decoupled -- in this case, worker that are able to connect to signals should know nothing about any database where I keep tasks/jobs. It's doable, but in my opinion worker should be just a slave that listens for tasks and executes them.